# DAG, Scala/Akka

Tags: scala, graph, akka

I was wondering the best implementation of a DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph) using Scala/Akka where each node can be potentially on different VMs, different computers.
Think of each node as a Scala actor who would only act on its direct parents (in graph terms), how would you implement this at a high level? There are several concepts in Akka that could be applied:
•   Normal actors with discards if the sender is not a direct parent
•   Event Bus and Classifiers
•   …
I am still struggling to choose a best approach, at least in theory, knowing that for a DAG, you need to be able to handle diamond scenarios (where a node depends on two or more nodes that in turn depend on one unique node).
Any pointers to papers, articles, ideas would be welcomed.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use Akka Remote with some DIYing